# React : How to make pagination in Loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, loopback

I am using `ReactJ`S and new to `ReactJS`. Could someone please help me how I can implement pagination through Loopback API .I want two thing One is to show limit data on per page and on every page data is rendering differently from each other .

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly these are 2 filters you want

1) [Skip](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Skip-filter.html)

2) [Limit](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Limit-filter.html)

Loopback have 2 filters for pagination one is `skip` means how much records you want to skip and `limit` and how much records you want to get after skipped records.

**For Example:**

You want to have 10 records per page

For page 1 you can use this api

This will get you first 10 records

```
/cars?filter[limit]=10&filter[skip]=0
```

For page 2 you can use this api

This will get you records from 10 to 20

```
/cars?filter[limit]=10&filter[skip]=10
```

For each page You have to change value for skip and you can simply calculate it by

```
skip = (page_number-1)*records_per_page
```

Comment: Actually I am beginner to React . Could you please help me to build this type pagination in React

Comment: Sure thing please tell me issues you are facing